# Specifying base class method template type (c++)

Tags: c++, inheritance, using, template-specialization, base-class

I am trying to create a class using tag dispatching for different method implementations, for different use cases.

The class has template methods, using the tags with template specialization for different behaviors with the same method signature.

---

### User scenarios:

1. I want one user to be able to set the tag when declaring the object and no longer care about the tag, when later using its methods.
2. I also want another user to use the tags more dynamically, e.g. use different tags in different parts of the code (with the same object).

---

Maybe it is wishful thinking that one class could do both these, without if-statements or other overhead? So I tried using two similarly named classes, which could be used for these two scenarios.

I am now trying to get a template subclass (used for scenario 1) to inherit from the base class (used for scenario 2) with all the members and methods, but also set the method template types (tags). A minimal example of what I am trying to describe is shown below (without tag dispatching).

---

**Is there a way to set the template type of a base class method template, without writing a wrapper method?**
E.g. using `using` (did get that to work though, see below).

---

The perfect solution would also use the same type name for both the template (subclass) and non-template (base) class, but I guess that is not allowed in the same namespace? This question is secondary to the above.

---

### Class definitions

```
// Base class declaration
class tA;

// Template specialization implementation
namespace detail
{
    template<typename T>
    void doSomethingImpl(const tA& a)
    {
        std::cout << "Does something default." << std::endl;
    }
    
    template<>
    void doSomethingImpl<int>(const tA& a)
    {
        std::cout << "Does something int'y" << std::endl;
    }
    
    template<>
    void doSomethingImpl<float>(const tA& a)
    {
        std::cout << "Does something float'y" << std::endl;
    }
}

// Base class definition
class tA
{
  public:    
    template<typename T>
    void doSomething() 
    {
        detail::doSomethingImpl<T>(*this);
    }
};


// Subclass, should set doSomething type in object declaration
template<typename T>
class tB : public tA
{
  public:
    // using tA::doSomething<T>; // error: a template-id may not appear in a using-declaration
                                 // What do do? I'd rather not use a wrapped method below.

    // Unwanted wrapper method
    void doSomething()
    {
        tA::doSomething<T>();
    }
};
```

---

### Usage

```
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Dynamic usage:" << std::endl;
    
    tA dynamicUsage{};
    dynamicUsage.doSomething<bool>();  // "Does something default"
    dynamicUsage.doSomething<int>();   // "Does something int'y"
    dynamicUsage.doSomething<float>(); // "Does something float'y"
   
    std::cout << "\nStatic usage:" << std::endl;
    
    tB<int> staticUsage{};
    staticUsage.doSomething();         // "Does something int'y"

    staticUsage.tA::doSomething<float>(); // This also works due to public inhertiance.
}
```